# Producer-consumer architecture over network in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I need a producer-consumer kind of architecture, where the producer puts data in a queue over and over, and then a consumer reads from that queue as fast as it can process the data.

For the producer and consumer running in separate processes we already have `multiprocessing`, with `Queue` where you have `put` and `get`. So even if the producer runs as 2-3 times the speed of the consumer, all the data is in the queue (assume memory use is not a problem) and the consumer just calls `q.get` whenever it needs to.

But I need the producer and consumer to be connected over a network, so probably tough a socket (but I am open to other methods). The big problem with sockets is that they do not separate objects automatically like queues do.

For a `multiprocessing.Queue` if I call `q.get` I get the next object, the queue takes care of how many bytes to read and recreates the object for me, `q.get` just returns the object. With a socket I have to `pickle.dumps` to send it and then I need to be careful how many bytes to read from the socket (in case there is more than 1 object in the socket) and then `pickle.loads` the result. The main problem is keeping track of object sizes.

If I put 10 objects of different sizes that add up to 1000 bytes in a `Queue` then the queue takes care of how many bytes to read for every object when calling `q.get`. For a socket if I pickle the 10 objects and send them, the socket has no idea how to split the big 1000 byte string inside it, and creating a mechanism for this means adding alot of new code.

Is there some kind of... socket-based `Queue` or similar?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no off-the-shelf implementation, so you need to implement your own wire protocol to read & chunk properly. This is for the case you really need it in python, for real world usage people usually end up either with message queues or zeromq

Answer (score 1):

This is usually solved with an external software that will act as a broker for the producer and consumer over the internet. There are a few open source projects you can look into;

- [RabbitMQ](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html)
- [Kafka](https://gist.github.com/NickLarsenNZ/e479c33f37a30ae4273f76dc2eab2a3e)
- [Redis](https://gist.github.com/igniteflow/1870027)
- [Celery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celery_(software))

They are all different in their own way, but they all have Python libraries you can easily `pip install` to begin using them. All of them will require that a third process is running to serve as the broker of messages.

Similarly, there are paid products for this as well - typically hosted in one of the big cloud providers - like [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).

This is not to say that it is not possible to create a custom socket or server implementation to do this... but, a lot of times in programming, it's best not to try to rebuild the wheel.